# django rest_framework viewset has no route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I started a new django application with django rest_framework. One thing is odd though - when I try the example from the quickstart it works fine: I get a route at `http://localhost:8000/users/` that I can query. But it doesn't work with my own app which is as minimal as it could be. My route `http://localhost:8000/listings/` is not available and I get no error. I'm using django 1.8.2 and djangorestframework 3.1.3.

settings.py:

```
#...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'listing',
)
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ] 
}
#...
```

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from listing.models import Listing


class ListingSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('description',)


class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'listings', ListingViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Listing(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
```

**Edit:**

The error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/

Using the URLconf defined in djangoway.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^__debug__/
    ^$ [name='api-root']
    ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='api-root']

The current URL, listings/, didn't match any of these.
```

**Edit:**
[Answered my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30859513/246241) and took the code down, because there was nothing odd with it.

Comment: _"Not available"_ - please, clarify. Is it 404 page? Shouldn't Django show defined url patterns on 404 page?

Comment: Sorry, it's early in the morning. Yes, it's 404.

Comment: shouldn't you separate out the code of `serializers`, `views` and `urls` into 3 separate files instead of 1

Comment: yes i should and I did in the first place. I put it together like this because it replicates the [Example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example) and also shows the behaviour.

Comment: Will replacing `urlpatterns = router.urls` with `urlpatterns = [url(r'^', include(router.urls))]` solve the problem?

Comment: @soon: no, it won't. same problem

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but have you tried to restart server?

Comment: @soon: Yes, I also tried different python versions: I went from pypy3 to cpython 3.4 to cpython 2.7. They all do the same. Also: There are no dumb questions at this point.

Comment: Strange behavior, cannot figure the mistake right now. Could you, please, share the project somewhere (GitHub, Bitbucket) so I can try to run it on my environment?

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/tback/routing_example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used the ModelViewSet:

```
class ListingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
                              ^^^^^
```

Thanks to xordoquy for pointing it out in the [issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3035) I opened.